# Normalize jquery mobile listview search

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091843/searching-with-accents-in-jquery-mobile?noredirect=1#comment31728867_21091843) I would like to make my jquery mobile listview filtering accent independent. So if you search for "Créteil" it would be the same as looking for "Creteil". Out of the box jQuery Mobile does make a distinction between accented and not accented characters, so if you type "Creteil" you won't get any results.

How can I make it so using the non-accented characters yields the same results as using their accented counterparts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700636/using-javascript-to-perform-text-matches-with-without-accented-characters

Comment: It's not. This is a question specific to jQuery-Mobile. I'm not asking how to perform the replacements; I am asking how to apply these normalizations over the specific listview control of jQM.

Comment: Maybe you could use `data-filtertext` to include a non-accented version? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete/ but then searching for Cretéil for example would not work.